# I will be joining the moderator strike [edit - now over]

Tags: discussion

**Edit**: following [an agreement being reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/294691) between the company and community representatives, I am no longer striking.

Following the announcement of a [new policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/what-is-the-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content/389583#389583) making it very difficult to moderate AI-generated content, I'll be [joining the network wide moderator strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) as of Monday 5th June.

The open letter says it better than I can, but in summary my opinion is that the new policy is completely ridiculous.

There's also now [a longer post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) about the reasons for the strike.

Comment: Some commentary from Jon Ericson (a former SE Community Manager) at https://jlericson.com/2023/06/02/strike_comentary.html. One tongue-in-cheek comment seemed apropos: *"Right now companies like OpenAI are setting the agenda. If you aren't using AI already, you gotta catch up. Time is running out! Looking at the graph I showed earlier and extrapolating the trend, Stack Overflow will have negative questions in 16 months or so. NO TIME TO WASTE!"*

Comment: Related: [Disappointed in StackExchange management](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2788/10997) and [Dear Stack Exchange: A Statement and a Letter from your Moderators](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2779/10997)